# element from each statement to declare input name jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

So here's the code I was trying to run:

`ul
  each account in accountlist
    li(class='no-bullets'): form(id='get-account-info'): input(type='hidden', name= account): button(class='btn', action='submit')= account`

It worked fine until I nested the input element.

Then it threw this error:
`Error: input is self closing and should not have content.`

Am I not allowed to use an element from an array to inform the attribute of an element, use an element from an array loop twice, or is there some syntax I messed up/missed when I was pouring through the docs, and every stack overflow question to find a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input element cannot have child elements in HTML.

Try this:

```
ul
  each account in accountlist
    li(class='no-bullets'): form(id='get-account-info'): input(type='hidden', name= account)
    button(class='btn', action='submit')= account
```

Also, the id of your form has to be unique.